# In Beneath the Planet of the Apes (1970), were there hibernation bunks in the crashed spaceship?

Tags: science-fiction-genre

In Beneath the Planet of the Apes (1970), were there hibernation bunks in the crashed spaceship?[image]

Comment: The sHip in the first film had four hibernation bunks.  I can find no definitive evidence that the ship in the second film was identical, but given that the second ship was a rescue mission, I would think it must have also had hibernation capability of some sort.  I do not think the writers gave it much thought.